# database en FireBase

Tags: android, firebase

Buenos días me encuentro tratando de conectar una BD con Firebase, toda la conexion y creacion esta bien, por el IDE que proporciona Android Studio.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo atento a sus respuestas, Gracias

Comment: Y la duda cual es?

Comment: Cual es la pregunta i/o problema?

Comment: Carlos, bienvenido, modifica tu pregunta, trata de agregar el código como texto para que sea más legible, revisa [ask] saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Donde dice `database.getReference()` lo tenes que reemplazar con `firebaseDatabase.getReference()` ya que no existe la variable `database` declarada en ningun lado y lo que buscas es crear una referencia.

Comment: Ayudanos a que el OP mejore la pregunta en base a [ask], responder a preguntas que no están correctamente realizadas pueden ser de utilidad únicamente a quien pregunta pero no a la comunidad, saludos.

Comment: Genial @Elenasys , gracias por la información

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, fue error mio. =)

Comment: Genial que te haya servido , un saludo